# The fastest way to transform date field into multiple fields in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table containing about 100.000 rows, with a specific nullable date field that I need to transform to multiple columns. these columns are accessible via a view.

for simplification purposes let's say I'm joining two tables called tab1 and tab2, the content of the two tables is of no importance except the date field from tab1

so far the solution I arrived to is the following :

```
create view result_view as 
   select to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY') AS year,
          to_char(t1.date, 'MM') AS month,
          to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day,
          t2.value as value
   from tab t1 left join tab2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

the current solution is taking so much time, any optimization?

Comment: time taken is not spent on `to_char` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a very big table containing about 100.000 rows,

That's not very big ;)

Run your query under `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see where the time is lost.

Other than that, I'd suggest to use `extract` instead of `to_char`.

E.g. `extract(YEAR from t1.date)` and the like.

Extract is SQL standard and returns numbers, not strings. This is often wanted.

More about extract: http://modern-sql.com/feature/extract

Comment: the description is modified to describe the question more objectively

Comment: @rachidelkedmiri You have removed the words *very big* from the question. But you did not follow my suggestions.

Comment: yup. extract, date_part or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: @MarkusWinand with extract the running time is reduced by half